# mysql select query with order by condition issue

Tags: mysql, select

this is my select query:

```
select 
    b.S_SORT,
    a.FABRIC1,
    c.BRNCH_CODE,
    a.XS_ALL,
    a.S_ALL,
    a.M_ALL,
    a.L_ALL,
    a.XL_ALL,
    c.LABEL_CODE,
    c.STATUS
from
    jo_det as a
        inner join
    jo_hdr as c ON a.TRAN_NO = c.TRAN_NO
        inner join
    branch as b ON b.BRNCH_CODE = c.BRNCH_CODE
where
    c.JO_NO = '1398'
ORDER BY B.S_SORT ASC
```

and this is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the sorting of column **S_SORT** is working fine. What i want to know is that how can I arrange the column of **FABRIC1** the 10-2218-0110 will be the first and 40-9515-0402 will be the last with each BRNCH_CODE.

From **S_SORT** : 1 to 3, the arrangement of FABRIC1 is fine, however in S_SORT: 4, the first fabric is 40-9515-0402 and the last is 10-2218-0110.

Is there a way that I can order the FABRIC1 just like the arrang from S_SORT: 1 to 3?

Comment: Maybe one more expression in ORDER BY will help? `ORDER BY B.S_SORT ASC, a.FABRIC1 ASC`

Comment: How do you expect this to work - if you're breaking groups order among two columns? The fact, that your `BRANCH_CODE` is arranged by 'groups' is only kind of 'luck' - in common case there will be not such behavior (because you ordering  only by `S_SORT`). I can't even imagine what do you mean with this.

Comment: @Nikola: that works for me now, but before I post this question I have tried that but with different way like this: ORDER BY FABRIC1, B.S_SORT ASC, its now working for me before, but that one is working for me just fine, Thank you :)

Comment: @AlmaDo: Hi, the answer below is working for me, and as what Nikola said, I just have to use that ORDER BY condition with 2 columns, its working for me now :) thank you

Comment: @Matthew then your question is not clear (or explanations were not well). In any case, if it's working, it's ok

Comment: `ORDER BY` result is depends on order of expressions - `ORDER BY FABRIC1, B.S_SORT ASC` differs from `ORDER BY B.S_SORT ASC, FABRIC1`.  In first clause MySQL sorts all data by `FABRIC1` and then sorts data by S_SORT in all groups with same values in FABRIC1 column.

Comment: @Nikola: ahh I see, so that how it works, thank you for explaining it to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more order by for **FABRIC1** as mentioned below :

```
select 
    b.S_SORT,
    a.FABRIC1,
    c.BRNCH_CODE,
    a.XS_ALL,
    a.S_ALL,
    a.M_ALL,
    a.L_ALL,
    a.XL_ALL,
    c.LABEL_CODE,
    c.STATUS
from
    jo_det as a
        inner join
    jo_hdr as c ON a.TRAN_NO = c.TRAN_NO
        inner join
    branch as b ON b.BRNCH_CODE = c.BRNCH_CODE
where
    c.JO_NO = '1398'
ORDER BY 
B.S_SORT ASC, 
a.FABRIC1 ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You just add it in your ORDER BY clause

```
select 
    b.S_SORT,
    a.FABRIC1,
    c.BRNCH_CODE,
    a.XS_ALL,
    a.S_ALL,
    a.M_ALL,
    a.L_ALL,
    a.XL_ALL,
    c.LABEL_CODE,
    c.STATUS
from
    jo_det as a
        inner join
    jo_hdr as c ON a.TRAN_NO = c.TRAN_NO
        inner join
    branch as b ON b.BRNCH_CODE = c.BRNCH_CODE
where
    c.JO_NO = '1398'
ORDER BY B.S_SORT ASC, FABRIC1 ASC
```

Comment: Yay thanks sir! Actually I have use this before but in the ORDER BY condition I use this one, 'ORDER BY FABRIC1, B.S_SORT ASC', But the results of this is not what I want. I do not know before that there are other ways in ORDER BY, thank again sir, big help! :D

Comment: The sequence of fields you use in your `ORDER BY` is important. It will sort from left to right. Since you switched the fields (first FABRIC1, then S_SORT), it will give a different order of records.